# How to check file is valid image or not using php?

Tags: php, file, file-type

i need your suggestions for checking image file. If a user will upload any file with changed extension type like (jpg,jpeg,bmp,png) how do we figure out that in PHP?
I don't want to check only file type extentions but i want to know that the uploaded file is not a malicious file by changing it's extention type. 
Like: we have hack.php file and we change it with hack.jpg file so how to we identify that this is not a valid file.

Comment: Why should that be of interest? If a user uploads something, then that is his own problem. Typically you only want to re-deliver that if it is requested. If someone uploaded a text file renamed somehow, then fine, he get's back a text file.

Comment: Have you done anything on your own yet? You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @arkascha that could open your application to security issues.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Can you explain how that is possible?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Only if you actually use such uploaded data and integrate it into your application logic. Which of course no one does _specifically because_ you cannot in any way trust data uploaded from the client side. Yes, you can deliver a file that contains something else than what it appears to hold at first. So what? That is not a "security issue".

Comment: @arkascha I was thinking of [this](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Hiding-Webshell-Backdoor-Code-in-Image-Files/) which is orthogonal to the issue at hand, but still

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That requires [server code that executes user provided data](https://blog.sucuri.net/2013/07/malware-hidden-inside-jpg-exif-headers.html). A bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) if exists. Else execute linux command of `file -i -b` on the file to get the answer.

Consider function as following:

```
function getFileType($file_name) {
        if(! function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
            $isUnix = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN' && DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '/';

            // check whether operating system is that of a UNIX type.
            if ($isUnix) {
                $type = null;
                exec('file -i -b ' . realpath($file_name), $type);
                $parts = @ explode(";", $type[0]); // can be of format text/plain;  charset=us-ascii 
                return trim($parts[0]);
            }

            // the file program/command does not exist on Windows.
            else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return mime_content_type($file_name);
        }
    }
```

You can also use [finfo-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) is you prefer.

Comment: Or you can spare yourself the shellout and use [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)